# Upgrade from 19.10 to 20.04 halt forever

Tags: upgrade, 20.04

It proceed to the step installing upgrades/installing snap snap store. Then halt forever. I see a process seems dead lock at snap remove gnome calculator. Any idea what to do? I guess kill the upgrade process will not be able to resume again. And I have to do fresh install instead. Seriously, if upgrade does not work do not offer it. Recent 5 releases never worked...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kill the remove process seems worked. Update is fine afterwards